# Acquiring Agilent 54642D oscilloscope waveform AND settings

Tags: settings, labview, waveform, visa, oscilloscope

I would like to use LabVIEW to capture the waveform already displayed on the screen of my Agilent oscilloscope (model 54642D). With this waveform, I would like to obtain the current settings of the oscilloscope-channel as well (volts/div, time/div, probe attenuation, delay, offset, cursors with frequency/period, etc.). In other words, I acquire a signal with the scope (not LabVIEW), adjust the scope settings to my liking on the front panel of the oscilloscope, and then I would like to capture the exact waveform displayed on the scope screen WITH the settings of the oscilloscope.

I have been using the project-style driver, found here: http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.model_page?p_model_id=724

This works for controlling the oscilloscope settings and acquiring a waveform, but it's not what I want. I simply want LabVIEW to capture the current state of the oscilloscope display and settings used.

Comment: Doesn't the LV driver for this device have the subVis to fetch what you need ?

Comment: Are you unable to get the settings and data separately?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, see my solution below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the solution, please visit the following link on NI's forum:

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Acquiring-Agilent-54642D-Oscilloscope-Waveform-AND-Settings/td-p/2157218#M695868